# MongoDB C# How to store an arbitary class

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Going with the restaurants demo dataset.  I've added an `orders` collection which will store orders from customers.

Different restaurants will want different shaped objects.

E.g.

Bill's burgers might want:

```
class BurgerOrder
{
    public IEnumerable<Burger> Burgers { get; set;}
}
```

Where-as the Golden Chinese might want:

```
class GoldenChinese
{
    public IEnumerable<ChineseOrders> { get; set; }
}
```

How can I store something like:

```
class Order
{
    public string RestaurantId { get; set; }

    public dynamic OrderDetails { get; set; }  // <-- This would hold an arbitary class,
                                               //     specific to a restaurant
    public DateTime ReceivedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use a common interface for all orders, and register all implementations through BsonClassMap.

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I'm trying not to do.

Comment: Then how do you expect an external service to understand how to deserialize a dynamic? To deserialize into an interface, MongoDB serializes the type with the data. I'm really not sure it can do the same thing with dynamics. If it can, it probably is not efficient.